# AWS DyanamoDb acces from .net core application

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-dynamodb

Locally I was able to access dynamoDb from my machine by using this configuration.

```
            AWSOptions awsOptions = configuration.GetAWSOptions();
            serviceCollection.AddDefaultAWSOptions(awsOptions);
            serviceCollection.AddAWSService<IAmazonDynamoDB>();
            serviceCollection.AddScoped<IDynamoDBContext, DynamoDBContext>();
```

Here is appsetings file configuration.

```
  "AWS": {
    "Profile": "preprod",
    "Region" :"eu-west-1"
  }
```

Whenever I try to release my changes to k8s cluster even tho there is kube2iamrole assign it. it gives me an error

```
System.ArgumentNullException
Value cannot be null. (Parameter ‘awsAccessKeyId’)
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'awsAccessKeyId')
   at Amazon.Runtime.ImmutableCredentials..ctor(String awsAccessKeyId, String awsSecretAccessKey, String token)
   at Amazon.Runtime.DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.FetchCredentials()
   at Amazon.Runtime.DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.GetCredentials()
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.SdkCache.CacheKey.Create(AmazonServiceClient client, Object cacheType)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.SdkCache.GetCache[TKey,TValue](AmazonServiceClient client, Object cacheIdentifier, IEqualityComparer`1 keyComparer)
   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.Table.LoadTableInfo()
   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.Table.LoadTable(IAmazonDynamoDB ddbClient, TableConfig config)
   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext.GetUnconfiguredTable(String tableName)
   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext.GetTargetTable(ItemStorageConfig storageConfig, DynamoDBFlatConfig flatConfig, DynamoDBConsumer consumer)
   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext.ConvertScan[T](IEnumerable`1 conditions, DynamoDBOperationConfig operationConfig)
   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext.ScanAsync[T](IEnumerable`1 conditions, DynamoDBOperationConfig operationConfig)
   at
```

Actually exception is quite clear that awsAccessKeyId is null so I believe that my registration way is not correct for the k8s cluster.

Did anyone experience it before?

Comment: the reason created the IAM role was to look at the old cluster whenever we switched to a new one. I was able to connect to dynamoDb

Answer (score 0):

AWS SDK's search for credentials in a defined order, [Credential and profile resolution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/creds-assign.html):

1. Credentials that are explicitly set on the AWS service client
2. A credentials profile with the name specified by a value in AWSConfigs.AWSProfileName.
3. A credentials profile with the name specified by the AWS_PROFILE environment variable.
4. The [default] credentials profile.
5. SessionAWSCredentials that are created from the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, and AWS_SESSION_TOKEN environment variables, if they're all non-empty.
6. BasicAWSCredentials that are created from the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment variables, if they're both non-empty.
7. IAM Roles for Tasks for Amazon ECS tasks.
8. Amazon EC2 instance metadata.

---

For this reason, you should ensure that you have valid credentials available in at least one of the sources allowed. Typically for ECS you define a [Container Instance Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/instance_IAM_role.html).